# labelling the edges on tikz figure

Tags: tikz-pgf

Here is my code. I want to label edges between SYMPTOMS ASSOCIATED WITH PH CHANGES ? and 
 HYPERSENSIVE ESOPHAGUS with "+ve" and between SYMPTOMS ASSOCIATED WITH PH CHANGES ? and acid unrelated heart burn as "-ve" . How can I do so?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
  invisible/.style={opacity=0},
  visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
  alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
    \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
  },
}
\tikzset{
block/.style = {
  rectangle,
  thick,
  text width=6em,
  align=center,
  rounded corners,
  draw=cyan!40!black,
  fill=cyan!20,
  inner ysep=10pt
  }
}
\node [block] at (0,6) (GERD){GERD};
\node [block] at (-3,4) (Esophagitis){Reflux esophagitis};
\node [block] at (0,4) (NERD){NERD};
\node [block] at (3,4) (Barret){Barret's esophagitis};
\node [block] at (0,2) (Ph){Ph testing};
\node [block] at (-3,0) (positive) {Ph +ve NERD};
\node [block] at (3,0) (Negative){Functional heart burn};
\node[] at (3,-2)(Symptoms) {\footnotesize {Symptoms associated with P\textsuperscript{H} changes?}};
\node [block] at (5, -4)(hypersensitive) {hypersensitive esophagus};
\node[block] at (1,-4)(unrelated){Acid unrelated heart burn};
\begin{scope}[cyan!40!black]
\draw[->] (GERD) -- (Esophagitis);
\draw[->] (GERD) -- (NERD);
\draw[->] (GERD) -- (Barret);
\draw[->] (NERD)--(Ph);
\draw[->](Ph)--(positive);
\draw[->](Ph)--(Negative);
\draw[->](Negative)--(Symptoms);
\draw[->](Symptoms)--(unrelated);
\draw[->](Symptoms)--(hypersensitive);
\end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For labelling edges, the new TikZ 3.0 provides a shorter syntax. Load the `quotes` library for this:

```
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
```

Now you can easily label your edges like this:

```
\draw[->](Symptoms) edge ["-ve" left] (unrelated);
```

It also works with `to`:

```
\draw[->](Symptoms) to ["+ve" right] (hypersensitive);
```

Bot lines changed this way gives, taken out the relevant part of the picture:

[image: edges with labels]

Answer (score 3):

You can use, for example,

```
\draw[->](Symptoms)--node[anchor=east]{-ve}(unrelated);
\draw[->](Symptoms)--node[anchor=west]{+ve}(hypersensitive);
```

[image: screenshot]

The `anchor` command controls the relative placement of the text; you can also add the `pos=<value>` key, where `<value>` takes any number between `0` and `1`.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        block/.style = {
            rectangle,
            thick,
            text width=6em,
            align=center,
            rounded corners,
            draw=cyan!40!black,
            fill=cyan!20,
            inner ysep=10pt
        }
    ]
    \node [block] at (0,6) (GERD){GERD};
    \node [block] at (-3,4) (Esophagitis){Reflux esophagitis};
    \node [block] at (0,4) (NERD){NERD};
    \node [block] at (3,4) (Barret){Barret's esophagitis};
    \node [block] at (0,2) (Ph){Ph testing};
    \node [block] at (-3,0) (positive) {Ph +ve NERD};
    \node [block] at (3,0) (Negative){Functional heart burn};
    \node[] at (3,-2)(Symptoms) {\footnotesize {Symptoms associated with P\textsuperscript{H} changes?}};
    \node [block] at (5, -4)(hypersensitive) {hypersensitive esophagus};
    \node[block] at (1,-4)(unrelated){Acid unrelated heart burn};
    \begin{scope}[cyan!40!black]
        \draw[->] (GERD) -- (Esophagitis);
        \draw[->] (GERD) -- (NERD);
        \draw[->] (GERD) -- (Barret);
        \draw[->] (NERD)--(Ph);
        \draw[->](Ph)--(positive);
        \draw[->](Ph)--(Negative);
        \draw[->](Negative)--(Symptoms);
        \draw[->](Symptoms)--node[anchor=east]{-ve}(unrelated);
        \draw[->](Symptoms)--node[anchor=west]{+ve}(hypersensitive);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As a comment, you can use the `positioning` library to construct diagrams like these, which allows you to specify the position of `nodes` using instructions such as `below=of...` which saves you having to specify the absolute position using coordinates (as you have done); of course, the output is ultimately what matters, and that wouldn't change very much, but it's good to know that there are alternatives `:)`